# block IP wordrpess for the next X minutes

Tags: ip

I would like to implement same example from here, about not allow you to publish another question after 40 minutes of your first question.

I have a Wordpress site and users ( register and no register) can submit post. That should be a really good idea to not allow users (checking IP ) to publish in the next 40 minutes for example if they actually published something.

Anybody can help me?
Thank for all ;)

Comment: WordPress.com sites are not in scope here, as that's a 3rd party service. Are you sure you meant to tag this question as WordPress.com? If so, please contact WordPress.com support and let us know and the question will be closed

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a post meta with ip value. And check it if ip available in database or not. you need to delete this meta key with value between 39 to 41 minute.
write a function to delete meta key with value in 40th minute. paste This function on single.php
Check ip available in db or not

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'meta_key=ip&meta_value='.$ip_address );
if ( $query->have_posts()){ 
//do something to block
}
```